Laravel Blade: x-base-component not rendering correct HTML tag
I am trying to create a dynamic Laravel Blade component that can render different HTML tags using a tag property. I am using a base-component and a button component. However, when I render the button component, it outputs an incorrect  tag in the HTML instead of the desired  tag.
Here is my setup:
button component:
@props([
    'type' => 'button', // The type of button (e.g., button, submit, reset)
    'name' => '', // The name attribute for the button (useful in forms)
    'value' => '', // The value attribute for the button (useful in forms)
    'disabled' => false, // Boolean to disable the button (adds the disabled attribute)
    'onclick' => '', // JavaScript code to execute on click
])

<x-base-component
    tag="button"
    {{ $attributes->merge(['class' => 'btn vn-button']) }}
    type="{{ $type }}"
    @if($name) name="{{ $name }}" @endif
    @if($value) value="{{ $value }}" @endif
    @if($disabled) disabled @endif
    @if($onclick) onclick="{{ $onclick }}" @endif
>
    {{ $slot ?? 'Button' }}
</x-base-component>

base-component:
@props([
    'tag' => 'div', // The HTML tag to use, default is <div>.
    'id' => '', // The ID attribute, for CSS or JavaScript targeting.
    'class' => '', // Additional CSS classes.
    'style' => '', // Inline styles.
    'title' => '', // Tooltip or additional information.
    'dataSelectors' => [], // Array of custom data-* attributes.
    'ariaLabel' => '', // ARIA label for accessibility.
    'role' => '', // Semantic ARIA role.
    'hidden' => false, // Boolean to add the hidden attribute.
])

<{{ $tag }}
    @if($id) id="{{ $id }}" @endif
    class="{{ $class }}"
    @if($style) style="{{ $style }}" @endif
    @if($title) title="{{ $title }}" @endif
    @if($hidden) hidden @endif
    @if($role) role="{{ $role }}" @endif
    @if($ariaLabel) aria-label="{{ $ariaLabel }}" @endif
    @foreach($dataSelectors as $key => $value)
        data-{{ $key }}="{{ $value }}"
    @endforeach
>
    {{ $slot }}
</{{ $tag }}>


Usage in a Blade file:
<x-button>Test</x-button>
Expected Output:
<button class="btn vn-button" type="button">
    Test
</button>

Current output:
<x-base-component tag="button" class="btn vn-button" type="button">
....
</x-base-component>

How can I make the base-component correctly render the dynamic tag value as the desired HTML tag (e.g.,  instead of )? Is there a known limitation or better approach for handling dynamic tags in Laravel Blade components?
Update:
I´VE TRIED TO USE X-DYNMIC-COMPONENT but the result is the same... I think it has something to do taht this is the nested component basically

@props([
    'tag' => 'div', // The HTML tag to use, default is <div>.
    'id' => '', // The ID attribute, for CSS or JavaScript targeting.
    'class' => '', // Additional CSS classes.
    'style' => '', // Inline styles.
    'title' => '', // Tooltip or additional information.
    'dataSelectors' => [], // Array of custom data-* attributes.
    'ariaLabel' => '', // ARIA label for accessibility.
    'role' => '', // Semantic ARIA role.
    'hidden' => false, // Boolean to add the hidden attribute.
])

<x-dynamic-component :component="$tag"
                     @if($id) id="{{ $id }}" @endif
                     class="{{ $class }}"
                     @if($style) style="{{ $style }}" @endif
                     @if($title) title="{{ $title }}" @endif
                     @if($hidden) hidden @endif
                     @if($role) role="{{ $role }}" @endif
                     @if($ariaLabel) aria-label="{{ $ariaLabel }}" @endif
                     @foreach ($dataSelectors as $key => $value)
                         data-{{ $key }}="{{ $value }}"
        @endforeach
>
    {{ $slot }}
</x-dynamic-component>


X-DYNMIC-COMPONENT: Make sure your button component passes the tag value to base-component and ensures that the component renders dynamically:
